# Duplicate a Button to another Activity (Favorite Button)

Tags: java, android

I am working on my first Application it is a Soundboard App. At the moment my app looks like [this](https://i.gyazo.com/e43b08fc8c614b64ef1af618b8b17b60.png).

There is a Tablayout with some sites ("Sounds1, Sound2, Sounds3") etc.
Now I added a new layout which is "Your favorite Sounds".
When a button is pressed a sound is played and if the button is long pressed they can share it.

My Aim: I want to add a second option if the user long clicks the Button, an option should become available to "Add to Favorites" along with the aforementioned option "Share Sound".

When the "Add to Favorites" option is selected, the button should also appear on their favorites list.

Please let me know if you need to see my Java code or XML in order to help me.

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi, so how are you planning on saving which buttons have been favorited? My suggestion would be to add a unique ID to each sound, and then save all these ID's in a list. 

Then on the Favorites activity you can read in this list and show the appropriate buttons.

Comment: All my buttons use a unique ID for every Button like button1, button2, etc
Thats the thing, I do not know how I am able to show a dialog "put to favourite list" and then which code will duplicate this "clicked button" to the favourtive list

Comment: When I say unique ID, I do not mean an android ID for the button, please think of your sound as separate from your button, you are not likely to "duplicate" a button in the way you describe, you should create a new button, that does the same thing, which is why you should save the name of the sound for example. I think you need to do more research into saving in android.

For the second part of your question, you wish to show a dialog which is a completely different question and you should not bundle the two tasks together. 

Take it slow, don't bite off more than you can chew.

Comment: Okey but one Question for example. All my buttons do have the function onclick = "xxxx" so in my MainAcitivty there is a xxxx method. if you click button1 it will go to switch case1. And it will start the Mediaplayer with the Sound, which is in my Raw directory. So lets say if the button will be duplicated and set to the "Favourite.xml"-Layout with same preferences wouldnt it do the same?

Comment: No, you would need to redefine the button and the click handler in your favourites activity.